# Flask not releasing memory

Tags: python, flask

I'll begin this question with pointing out that I'm very new to web development.

Now to the point: I've recently built a rather small `Flask` application that loads data and then outputs visualizations of it using `bokeh`. And as such it will have to keep quite a lot of data stored in memory (about 10-20 mb). This in itself is not really a problem, however, the application does not release the objects in memory after the view functions have sent the requests. Which means that after just a few uses the app will have drained most of the memory.

My question is therefore: How do I force `Flask` to release the used objects after the view functions have returned any requests? Or am I going about this problem the wrong way? It could be worth mentioning that I use the built in server of `Flask` as we're still only prototyping. 
¨
Thanks, Tingis

**EDIT** Here's one of my view functions. What it does is that it loads data from a db using `SQLAlchemy` and then does some timeseries manipulations (such as a kernel density estimate and calculating cumulative return) and outputs a joined `div` and `script` string of a `bokeh` figure, which are the variables ending with `_plt`.

```
from app import app
from app.business_logic.classes.interface_classes import Company
from app.business_logic.functions.functions import get_session

@app.route('/analysis_tool/company_performance', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def analysis_tool__company_performance():
    session = get_session()

    companies_to_analyse = {
        'Company A': {'ts_to_use': 'Returns of Company A'},
        'Company B': {'ts_to_use': 'Returns of Company B'}
    }

    chosen_company = request.form.get('security')
    types_of_plots = {}

    if chosen_company is not None:
        company = Company(session, chosen_company)
        company.load_company()

        company.load_timeseries(companies_to_analyse[chosen_platform]['ts_to_use'])
        company.unpack_observations_of_ts_as_df()

        ret_df = company.manipulate_dataframe('convert timeseries to returns',
                                               frequency='monthly',
                                               ts_type=company.loaded_ts_orm_obj.ts_type_name)
        cum_ret_df = company.manipulate_dataframe('calculate cumulative return', df=ret_df)

        cum_ret_plt = company.plot_dataframe(cum_ret_df, legend=False)
        kde_plt = company.plot_kde(ret_df)

        types_of_plots = {'Cumulative_return': cum_ret_plt, 'KDE': kde_plt}

    return render_template('plotting/plot_using_panels.html',
                           items=sort_dictionary(platforms_to_analyse),
                           plot_types=sort_dictionary(types_of_plots),
                           selected=chosen_company)
```

Does this help?

**EDIT 2** I tried the solution that was provided in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740832/need-help-identifying-a-memory-leak-involving-matplotlib-and-flask), by adding a `gc.collect()` after each call to the plotting interface, as well as the function

```
@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    gc.collect()
```

But the memory still isn't released.

Comment: We'd need to see at least a section of the code to see why it is holding the memory.

Comment: Of course, only trouble is that I've left the office for today. Can I get back to you tomorrow?

Comment: @DanielCasserly Does the above piece of code help you, or do you require more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help identifying a memory leak involving matplotlib and flask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740832/need-help-identifying-a-memory-leak-involving-matplotlib-and-flask)

Comment: what does your `get_session` function do? I've got a feeling it's a circular class dependency, and the gc doesn't know which object (session or company) to `del` first so it just keeps them in memory

Comment: I think @LuisFHernandez is on to something. try wrapping the session reference in a `weakref.ref()` call.

Comment: Hey guys! Sorry for not responding in a while, completely forgot about it. While the problems persisted I solved it by rebooting the app every night. And the code has now been retired in favor of a better iteration. But I could take a look and see if it is as you guys suggest. Will get back tomorrow

Comment: How are you deploying Flask? While this may be in your rear-view, I think it's fair to say rebooting is more of a bandaid than a solution. If you're using matplotlib/pyplot, a common error that would cause this is failing to call `pyplot.clf` otherwise each plotting will just accumulate in memory.

Comment: Perhaps a function that periodically runs & forces the garbage collector to run `gc.collect()` would be a viable solution if you can't find the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you are creating a circular reference between `get_session` and the Company object?